# How can I use the WASM/client-side version of HttpClient in a Blazor Server Application?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I want to be able to transition between Blazor Webassembly and Blazor Server easily. HttpClient is implemented as:

- server-side in a Blazor Server Application
- client-side WASM in a Blazor Webassembly Application

**is there a way to use the client-side version of HttpClient, in a Blazor Server Application?**

Comment: Can you explain  what is  `the client-side version of HttpClient`?

Comment: @YiyiYou The client-side version makes HTTP requests from the visitor's browser. For example an HTTP POST request is done by the visitor's browser, instead of on the server-side, where the website is hosted. This is similar to how JavaScript code runs in the browser. But in this case WASM code runs in the browser

Comment: i'm guessing that it is not possible, because it makes reasoning about the security of Blazor Server Applications more difficult